# Elegant way to split a matrix (or array) at arbitrary chunk in Python

Tags: python, numpy, split

I am doing k-fold cross validation on a dataset and for that I need to split my data into two, one is the train set and other the test set.

So far I have managed to split the dataset to be my testset by:

```
testindices = range(idx*testsize, (idx*testsize) + testsize) 
testset = dataset[testindices,0:numfeatures]
```

where idx is that kth fold or in other words the chunk starting index. This is easy. I am stuck with how to get the other part, i.e. the trainset? Its basically a set different operation whereby the resulting trainset is all but the testset?

Comment: I see you are working with numpy, so in this case you can use [sklearn cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) and split your data or even train your model with k folds.

Comment: @FranciscoZamora-Martínez Yes, I check it and seems it should work but somehow my python cannot find the module sklearn.cross_validation. I need to do upgrading. Any other simple way to split?

Answer (score 0):

I got it and

```
folds = np.concatenate([range(idx+1,10), range(0,idx)])
trainindices = range(0,0)
for i in folds:
    trainindices = np.concatenate([trainindices, range(i*testsize, (i*testsize) + testsize)])


trainindices = map(int,trainindices)
#print trainindices
```